# launch is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to run [the simplest example with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/test/guide/example-basic-01.kt):

```
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*

    fun main() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(1000L)
            println("${Thread.currentThread().name}: World")
        }
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name}: Hello")
        Thread.sleep(2000L)
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name}: Finish!")
    }
```

And my *build.gradle* file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    // Consider moving these values to `gradle.properties`
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0-rc-146'
    ext.kotlin_gradle_plugin_version = '1.3.0-rc-198'
    ext.kotlinx_coroutines = '1.0.0-RC1'

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlin-eap" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.1.51"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
group 'by.kotlin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName = 'MainKt'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlin-eap" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutines"   
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

But when I run this example, I've got the following errors:

```
e: ...Main.kt: (6, 17): 'launch(CoroutineContext = ..., CoroutineStart = ..., [ERROR : Bad suspend function in metadata with constructor: Function2]<CoroutineScope, Continuation<Unit>, Any?>): Job' is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2
e: ...Main.kt: (7, 9): Suspend function 'delay' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
e: ...Main.kt: (7, 9): 'delay(Long): Unit' is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
```

Why do these errors occur? I'm completely confused, because the first error says that launch "is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2", but I use Kotlin 1.3 in my build.gradle file (in particular, '1.3.0-rc-146')...

**UPD**

It seems that the reason of problem is in IntelliJ IDEA Settings:

[image]

But how to fix it, if the latest language version, which can be selected there, is 1.2, not 1.3?

Comment: You have three different versions of Kotlin in your build.gradle: 1.2.51, 1.1.51 and 1.3.0-rc. Please change all of the places to use the same version, then everything will compile correctly. Also make sure that the IDE plugin you're using is also 1.3 RC.

Comment: @yole, I undate Kotlin plugin (now it's the latest version: 1.2.71-release-IJ2018.2-1), but anyway the latest language version that can be selected is 1.2, not 1.3... Does it mean that the only way to use Kotlin 1.3 is install new version of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: To install a prerelease version of the Kotlin plugin, go to Tools → Kotlin → Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates, select “Early Access Preview 1.3” in the Update channel drop-down list, and then click Check for updates. Note that you still don't need to change the IDEA settings manually; if all versions are specified correctly, the Gradle build will work and the settings will be synchronized.

Comment: Finally I've updated Kotlin plugin, and the example was executed successfully, but IntelliJ IDEA anyway underlines "launch" and "delay" keywords in red.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have updated Kotlin to 1.3. You can do this from `Preference->Lanugage & Framework->Kotlin Updates`

Then change the version of `kotlin.jvm` plugin to `1.3.0` in gradle. (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm)

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.3.0"
}
```

And for including `coroutines`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core', version: '1.0.0'
}
```

It should be fine now.

Answer (score 4):

You must change kotlin plugin version

Your current kotlin plugin version is 1.2.51

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51"
}
```

this is correct

```
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
     ext.kotlin_gradle_plugin_version = '1.3.0'
     ext.kotlinx_coroutines = '1.0.0'

     repositories {
         maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlin-eap" }
         mavenCentral()
         jcenter()
         google()
     }
     dependencies {
         'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:'+kotlin_version
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually updating the Kotlin-IntelliJ Plugin.

First, download the newer version of the Kotlin plugin that is compatible with your version of IntelliJ https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/stable

Then in IntelliJ's Settings -> Plugins, click on the settings/gear icon on the top-right side. From there choose **Install Plugin from Disk...**, choose the zip file you got from the intellij website. Then it will ask you to restart the IDE, and that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

If it has started to occur only recently then chances are two links are generating same file with same name, in this case removing one of your recent file from `build.gradle` will help you resolving the issue.

In my case this was causing the issue

```
implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.Ferfalk:SimpleSearchView:0.2.0'
```

After removing first one out of them the issue was resolved.